# What does `unsigned` in MySQL mean and when to use it?

Tags: mysql, types

What does "unsigned" mean in MySQL and when should I use it?

Answer (score 603, accepted):

[MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) says:

> All integer types can have an optional
>   (nonstandard) attribute UNSIGNED.
>   Unsigned type can be used to **permit
>   only nonnegative numbers in a column**
>   or **when you need a larger upper
>   numeric range** for the column. For
>   example, if an INT column is UNSIGNED,
>   the size of the column's range is the
>   same but its endpoints shift from
>   -2147483648  and 2147483647 up to 0 and 4294967295.

**When do I use it ?**

Ask yourself this question: *Will this field ever contain a negative value*?
If the answer is no, then you want an `UNSIGNED` data type.

A common mistake is to use a primary key that is an auto-increment `INT` starting at **zero**, yet the type is `SIGNED`, in that case you’ll never touch any of the negative numbers and you are reducing the range of possible id's to half.

Comment: values representing the 'sizes' of things, like the quantity of a particular item on an order, or the distance between two locations, will typically be unsigned

Comment: Great answer, seems strange that mysql wouldn't default integers to unsigned when they are auto incrementing identities?

Comment: If you want more clear answer then look this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11515613/6335029

Comment: @wired00 Perhaps part of the reason is that `UNSIGNED` is a non-standard MySQL feature.

Comment: yeah, imagine you have a negative ID

Answer (score 2):

### What does "unsigned" mean in MySQL:

In schema building (database design), the `unsigned` integer is an integer that can only hold a **positive** (non-negative) value.

In the context of mySQL, the `unsigned` **method** used to specify that column should only hold a positive value.

### when should I use it?

It's good practice in schema building to assign the columns that hold foreign key (as id) to `unsigned` method to make sure that column only holds positive value and **prevent erros and unexpected behaviors** in queries that use that column.