# Create mysql table limit integer to positive values

Tags: mysql, constraints

I try to create a table with an INTEGER attribute which should be limited to positive numbers. I know there is an UNSIGNED option, but that does the wrong thing. As it allows adding -10 as a value. It will just make a 10 out of it.

Is it possible to deny a wrong entry? I tried using CHECK

```
DROP TABLE Produkt;
CREATE TABLE Produkt (
    Bezeichnung VARCHAR(237) PRIMARY KEY,
    ProduktNr INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Produktart VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT "XXX",
    CONSTRAINT onlyPositive CHECK(ProduktNr >= 0)
);
```

But I can still add -10 as a value... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check this answer to understand signed and unsigned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515594/when-should-i-use-unsigned-and-signed-int-in-mysql

Comment: The unsigned one can't hold negative numbers.

Comment: unsigned can not hold negative numbers but it does not prevent you from adding negative ones... They will just be converted to positive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) In a strict [sql_mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables) if you define your column as

```
ProduktNr INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
```

and then try to insert a negative value you'll get an error

> ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'ProduktNr' at row 1

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c505/1)** demo. *Uncomment insert statement and click `Build Schema`*

2) MySQL still lacks support for `CHECK` constraints. [The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html).

3) On a side note: don't use a `VARCHAR(237)` column as a `PRIMARY KEY`, especially if you're using InnoDB engine (all secondary indices on the table also include PK values).

Comment: Why on earth would you implement a feature CHECK and then ignore it? :D Thanks for the sql_mode. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Can i use unsigned on double data type?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just add the check without naming the constraint. This seemed to work for me:

```
CREATE TABLE Produkt (
    Bezeichnung VARCHAR(237),
    ProduktNr INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Produktart VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT "XXX",
    PRIMARY KEY (Bezeichnung),
    CHECK(ProduktNr >= 0)
);
```

I also moved the declaration of the primary key. I'm not 100% certain that you can declare a key the same time as a field, but I did put what I knew.

Comment: Hi. The naming constraint just helps to keep track if you want to change it later. Nothing else. The system still does not prevent you from adding negative numbers. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d988a/1