# Error Cannot add foreign key constraint MySQL Error 1215

Tags: mysql

I was creating a database and I want to make relation between tables "Member" and  "Group_Member". But when I make the column "Memp_Id" as a foreign Key in table "Group_Member" as the [pictur](http://imgur.com/edit)e shown this error appear.
I have checked the data type but both are the same. What I have to do now?

Comment: picture looks great...

Comment: http://imgur.com/edit

Comment: @mostafahashim maybe you are setting id's in GroupMember table ,that yout Membetr table doesnot have.

Comment: Is there already data in the table?

Comment: No, the table "group_Member" Is Empty , no data yet to add

Comment: @mostafahashim can you display the errors which you are getting setting foreign key and query you are using for setting foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reasons for error code 1215** cannot add foreign key constraint are listed in  [percona's article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/04/06/dealing-mysql-error-code-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint/), but in the most cases the reasons are as follows:

- **child table**'s potential `foreign key` **contains ids which is not present in parent table**, but
  your child table 'Group_Member' is empty so it is not applicable for
  you.
- The Local Key, Foreign Table or Column in the Constraint References
  **Have a Typo**
- The Column the Constraint Refers to Is **Not of the Same Type or Width**
  as the Foreign Column, for e.g.if **primary key has data type and width `int(11)`** then **foreign key's type and width also has to be as `int(11)`**
- Different Charsets/Collations Among the Two Table/Columns, for example if **primary key has collation `utf8_unicode_ci` and foreign key has collation as `latin1_general_ci`** then error will occur, so it should be the same.
- The **Parent Table Is Not Using InnoDB**, for setting foreign key, if your parent table is of type `MyISAM` then it will show above error #1252 so it should be `InnoDB`.
- The **Parent Table Is Partitioned**, you should check partition also.
- Using **SET DEFAULT for a Constraint Action**, like Default `NULL` on PK or FK so Dont use Default on these keys.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure they are both the same datatype and check if unsigned is the same on both, and that if you already have group_member rows then mem_id values will need to exist in the members table.

See here for more clarity of what unsigned means,
[What does "unsigned" in MySQL mean and when to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895692/what-does-unsigned-in-mysql-mean-and-when-to-use-it)

Comment: yes , the table "group_Member" Is Empty , no data yet to add

Comment: and check if unsigned is the same on both,plz explain more

Comment: unsigned is an attribute u can define on columns with integer type