# ask about php summarize 01 + 01 = 02

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to make a id in database

> id_user => data type 'varchar'

I want my id to start from `00`, `01`, `02`, and so on.
And to make new id, I count the all the rows, and the result from count will be added by 01.

Example:

```
$id=array(00,01,02);
$count_exist_id = $count($id)
$new_id= '00' + $count_exist_id
```

and I hope the new id must be `'03'` and it will be store to database in table user column `id_user`

Comment: Store `ID`s as number without `0` at the beginning, and than add zero at front/end, in your template.

Comment: How is `01` different from `1`?

Comment: ok i need for make id, it just make code for three, so i can make different between parents/root and childs/leave

Comment: linking parents and children together that way is a VERY bad idea if you ask me... that is not a normalized approach and will lead to further troubles for sure. If that relationship is important, it should be formalized through normalization...

Comment: @Bartdude can you help me for another way to make linking parent and childrens, i really need it for make a tree like a family structure

Answer (score 2):

You can use `INT(x) ZEROFILL`, to add 0 before the number. '1' => '001'

With **INT ZEROFILL**, you have `AUTO_INCREMENT`. ;)

```sql
CREATE TABLE user (
   id_user INT(8) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   PRIMARY KEY(id_user)
);
```

If you use `UNSIGNED`, you optimize your table, and you save one BIT, to get bigger number.

See :

- [What is the benefit of zerofill in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256469/what-is-the-benefit-of-zerofill-in-mysql)
- [How can I set autoincrement format to 0001 in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611340/how-can-i-set-autoincrement-format-to-0001-in-mysql)
- [What does "unsigned" in MySQL mean and when to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895692/what-does-unsigned-in-mysql-mean-and-when-to-use-it)

Answer (score 1):

An easier approach would be to calculate the next id as an integer, and then pad it to a two character string:

```
$id = array(00,01,02);-
$count_exist_id = count($id);
$new_id = str_pad($count_exist_id, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: thanks for answer, i get it, and one problem again, i want make the child's from id, where `id_child = id_parent + 1 character` example : id_parent = (00) and id_child must be '001' ||  id_parent = (01) and id_child must be '010','011','012'